# Python script subprocess cant write Popen file

Tags: python

I've written a script to call `wmic Process` and write the result to a file.

This script runs fine in the interactive interpreter, but not when run as a python script.

```
'''
args = shlex.split("wmic process")
args = shlex.split("wmic process get executablePath")
print(args)
ic', 'process', 'get', 'executablePath']
a = open("sagol.txt","w")
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = a)
a.close()
p.kill()
'''
import shlex,subprocess
args = shlex.split("wmic Process")
a = open("salam.txt","w")
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = a)
print(p)
a.close()
p.kill()
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, don't give a link.

Comment: What goes wrong? In other words, what behavior do you see when you try to run the code as a script?

Answer (score 0):

You close the input stream and kill the started process before it really has a chance to write the output file.

Try waiting for the process to finish instead of killing it:

```
import shlex,subprocess
args = shlex.split("wmic Process")
a = open("salam.txt","w")
p = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = a)
print(p)
p.wait()
a.close()
```

Comment: very thank you edit my english and script thank you.